# Play a edge animation on click from an external html button

Tags: jquery, html, adobe-edge

My animation from adobe edge is on play when the browser loads the page. I would like to play the animation only if the visitor click a button (id="trigger") on my html page. I precise that i don't want the button to be a part of my stage/animation.

I read responses that mention files I don't have in my animation so here are the files I have :

edge.6.0.0.min.js and "namestage"_edge.js

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose you are running with Jquery just put the snippet from your adobe edge animation into a click function just as below.

```
jQuery('#ID OF YOUR BUTTON').click(function () {
  AdobeEdge.loadComposition('animation', 'EDGE-XXXXXX', {
    scaleToFit: "width",
    centerStage: "horizontal",
    minW: "0px",
    maxW: "undefined",
    width: "XXXXpx",
    height: "XXXpx"
  }, {
  dom: []
  }, {
  dom: []
  });

}
```